# Get button closer to input field

Tags: html, css, forms

I have an input and button on the same line but they sit far apart.

How can I bring them closer?

[image: Email & Subscribe Form Buttons]

**HTML**

```
<form action="https://moneynest.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=9ccf2d2219536b32eaae3c3d1&amp;id=33b662ad0d" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate> 
    <div class="input-group"> 
        <input type="email" name="EMAIL" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" id="mcinputform-front" required autofocus> 
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" onClick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'SumoMe', eventAction: 'Conversion', eventLabel: 'CTA bottom email signup on bankrupt footballers page'})";>Subscribe!</button>
                    <input id="group_32" style="display: none;" checked="checked" name="group[12353][32]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
                    <input id="group_4194304" style="display: none;" checked="checked" name="group[12353][4194304]" type="checkbox" value="1" /><!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
                <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_9ccf2d2219536b32eaae3c3d1_33b662ad0d" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
            </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
#signupform-front {
    background-color: lightgray;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
}
#signupinput-front {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 50%;
}
#mcsignupbutton-front {
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
}
#mcinputform-front {
    max-width: 50%;
}
```

[Check it here](https://www.moneynest.co.uk/frustrating-newsletter-signup-box/)

Comment: you set a width of 10%, if you don't like this, try setting a different width?

Comment: Please format your code such that it can be analyzed without scrolling (or, if not possible, with minimal scrolling). I think that the issue is where you declared the `span` though).

Comment: @FDavidov - please be more specific (edited to make more readable),

Comment: Please remove useless parts of your code (like onclick and more), fix the issue where you put a <div> inside a <span> and use a snippet.

Comment: @cloned - please be more specific.

Comment: Thanks @alexandreAnnic - that fixed the issue :)

Comment: change the info-group display to block

Comment: Yeap, wrong nesting of `span` (I get you fixed it already, right?).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following `CSS`.

The top class will make the div they are contained in 100% then you can control the size of each element, reducing it will put it on one line for you. The last class will add spacing left of the button.

```css
.input-group {
  width: 100%;
}

.input-group .form-control {
  width: 20%;
}

.btn-default {
  margin-left: 2%
}
```